# Structure of $FILE_NAME attribute in NTFS file system

Tags: windows, ntfs

I'm reading about the NTFS attribute types and it come to the $FILE_NAME attribute structure. Here it is:

```
Offset Size Description
~      ~    Standard Attribute Header
0x00   8    File reference to the parent directory.
0x08   8    C Time - File Creation
0x10   8    A Time - File Altered
0x18   8    M Time - MFT Changed
0x20   8    R Time - File Read
0x28   8    Allocated size of the file
0x30   8    Real size of the file
0x38   4    Flags, e.g. Directory, compressed, hidden
0x3c   4    Used by EAs and Reparse
0x40   1    Filename length in characters (L)
0x41   1    Filename namespace
0x42   2L   File name in Unicode (not null terminated)
```

What is "Filename Namespace" at the offset 0x41? I know a little about namespace i think. How can it be stored in just 1 byte? Can anyone clear this for me? Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

It describes the "traits" of a filename, i.e. length, allowable characters, etc. It is not a "string" in itself (like a C++/C#/etc. namespace).

I found a document [here](http://dubeyko.com/development/FileSystems/NTFS/ntfsdoc.pdf), of which I have frankly no idea of its validity.

But anyway, it describes the namespaces as such (which makes it quite obvious, see chapter 13.2.):

> 0: POSIX
>
> This is the largest namespace. It is case sensitive and
>   allows all Unicode characters except for NULL (0) and Forward Slash
>   '/'. The maximum name length is 255 characters. N.B. There are some
>   characters, e.g. Colon ':', which are valid in NTFS, but Windows will
>   not allow you to use.
>
> 1: Win32
>
> Win32 is a subset of the POSIX
>   namespace and is case insensitive. It uses all the Unicode characters,
>   except: '"' '*' '/' ':' '<' '>' '?' '\' '|' N.B. Names cannot end with
>   Dot '.', or Space ''.
>
> 2: DOS
>
> DOS is a subset of the Win32 namespace,
>   allowing only 8 bit upper case characters, greater than Space '', and
>   excluding: '"' '*' '+' ',' '/' ':' ';' '<' '=' '>' '?' '\'. N.B. Names
>   must match the following pattern: 1 to 8 characters, then '.', then 1
>   to 3 characters.
>
> 3: Win32 &DOS
>
> This namespace means that both the
>   Win32 and the DOS filenames are identical and hence have been saved in
>   this single filename record.

So the field can be one byte, because it just contains a number identifying the respective namespace in use.

Comment: Thank you very much sir!

Comment: «I have frankly no idea of its validity» It is indeed valid. The NTFS doc was written by the authors of the `ntfs-3g` Linux driver and is also extensively quoted in [*Forensic File System Analysis* by Brian Carrier](http://www.digital-evidence.org/fsfa/).

Comment: You are welcome. :) Besides, I got the title wrong! It is actually *File System Forensic Analysis*.